# JavaScript Switch Statement - Synonyms in a single Case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I am trying to design a page where several questions will be asked to the user, who types the answers in a textbox.

I am using a Switch Statement to generate different comments to different answers.

The same answer can be typed in many different ways. For example, it is possible that instead of typing "yes" the user types "yeah" or "you bet".

Is there a way to treat all of the possible answers as a single thing, to avoid having something like this:

```
switch (answers) {
    case "Yes":
    case "Yep":
    case "Yeah":
    case "You bet":
    case "Sure":
    case "Absolutely":
        text = "Me too.";
        break;
    case "No":
    case "Nope":
    case "Nah":
    case "I hate it":
    case "I do not":
    case "Not at all":
        text = "Why not?";
        break;
    default:
        text = "What?"
```

I would like to have a separate file with all possible synonyms for all the expected answers in the page.

That way, I could have something like this, and it would show the comment for the "Yes Case", instead of the comment for "Default", even when the user types "You bet", or "Yeah", or any other synonym:

```
    switch (answers) {
    case "Yes":
        text = "Me too.";
        break;
    case "No":
        text = "Why not?";
        break;
    default:
        text = "What?"
```

This is what I am working with:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var answers = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    switch (answers) {
        case "Yes":
        case "Yep":
        case "Yeah":
        case "You bet":
        case "Sure":
        case "Absolutely":
            text = "Me too.";
            break;
        case "No":
        case "Nope":
        case "Nah":
        case "I hate it":
        case "I do not":
        case "Not at all":
            text = "Why not?";
            break;
        default:
            text = "What?"
    }
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p>Do you like waffles?</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Answer</button>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach:

```js
{
  const questions = [
    { 
      text: 'Do you like waffles?',
      inputs: {
        yes: ['yes', 'yep', 'yeah'],
        no: ['no', 'nope', 'nah']
      },
      replies: {
        yes: 'Me too.',
        no: 'Why not?',
        other: 'What?'
      }
    }, 
    { 
      text: 'Do you like pasta?',
      inputs: {
        yes: ['yes', 'yep', 'yeah'],
        no: ['no', 'nope', 'nah']
      },
      replies: {
        yes: 'Me too!',
        no: 'Why not?!',
        other: 'What?!'
      }
    }, 
  ];
  
  let currentQuestionIndex = -1;
  
  function goToNextQuestion() {
    let currentQuestion = questions[++currentQuestionIndex];
    document.getElementById('myQuestion').innerHTML = currentQuestion.text;
    document.getElementById('myInput').value = '';
    document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
  }
  
  function answer() {
    let currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
    const input = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    const replyKey = Object.keys(currentQuestion.inputs)
      .find(inputKey => currentQuestion.inputs[inputKey].includes(input)) 
        || 'other';
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = currentQuestion.replies[replyKey];
    if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length - 1) {
      goToNextQuestion();
    }
  }
  
  goToNextQuestion();
}
```

```html
<p id="myQuestion"></p>
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="answer()">Answer</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

**Note**: additional wrapping brackets are there to prevent polluting the global scope with constants. Requires ES6 though--you can get rid of them if you're OK with global variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way to make these "const inputs" work with a textbox, instead of a window prompt, like in your suggestion? I have updated my post, adding a code snippet with what I have so far. Can I make your solution work in that environment?

Comment: Thanks again, and I'm really sorry to bother you whith what must be obvious things... But I have another problem. I cannot have constant replies for those inputs since those inputs will be used to answer other questions with different replies.

For example:

- Do you like Waffles?
- Yes.
- Me too.

-Do you know who I am?
- Yes.
- You do?!"

(Same input, different replies)

That's why I was trying to come up with a Switch Statement for each question. I wold like it to show a unique reply if the user types any value of a pre-determined array.

Comment: Are you trying to make a full chatbot, or is this just an exercise? If this is the former, you should probably look for existing tools/libraries, which there are tons of. If that's the latter, then it's hard to help you without knowing the full extent of your requirements. What you probably need is to store some kind of conversation tree, with questions linking to other questions (each with different possible answers) and so on.

Comment: This is just an exercise. I don't need anything too complex. I will have ten pages. Each will have a question for the user to answer. Once he gives an acceptable answer (one of the switch cases), he will get a custom reply and will move on to the next page/question. There will be no conversations. Each page/question will be independent from the others.

Comment: See my last edit. I did that a bit fast so you might have to clean a couple things up but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is not quite what I was looking for. But I guess it will do the job, for now.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to have 2 arrays or sets, one with all the Yes responses and another with all the No responses and check whether the input matches any of the values in the arrays/sets before getting into the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still a beginner. I've studies arrays so I think I can do that part. But how do I make it check if the input matches any of the values in the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object and a function which iterates the answers and phrases with their normalized (lower case) strings.

```js
function x(answer) {
    var check = {
            answers: [
                {
                    phrases: ["yep", "yeah", "you bet", "sure", "absolutely"],
                    text: "Me too."
                },
                {
                    phrases: ["no", "nope", "nah", "i hate it", "i do not", "not at all"],
                    text: "Why not?"
                }
            ],
            text: "What?"
        };

    answer = answer.toLowerCase();
    return (check.answers.find(o => o.phrases.includes(answer.toLowerCase())) || check).text;
}

console.log(x('No'));
console.log(x('Sure'));
console.log(x('Whatever!'));
```